# Django admin changelist view title

Tags: django, filter, view, django-admin

How can I pass filter value to change list view title? I have admin page for reports, and I want to store date in the title, so it looks like this : *"Reports summary for day 24-01-2021"* and I want to get date from list filter *reports__report_date*

```
class AdminReportsProxy(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Admin model, that creats site of reports summary"""

    model = ReportsProxy
    actions = None
    search_fields = [
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
    ]
    list_display = [
        "get_salesman",
        "get_number_of_meetings_today",
        "get_number_of_meetings_tomorrow",
        "get_number_of_sales",
        "get_number_of_recommandations",
        "get_net_sales",
        "get_report_date",
        "edit_report",
    ]
    list_filter = [
        ("reports__report_date", DateRangeFilter),
        NetSalesOrder,
    ]

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = {'title': f'Reports summary for day:{}'}
        return super(AdminReportsProxy, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the overridden function `changelist_view`, just access the query parameters that have been passed by DateRangeFilter widget they should look like this

`your_filtered_field__gte` -> for the from date

`your_filtered_field__lte` -> for the to date

like the following:

```
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        date_from = request.GET.get("reports__report_date__gte", None)
        date_to = request.GET.get("reports__report_date__lte", None)
        if date_from and date_to:
            # If these two values are available, you can replace the title of the page.
            extra_context = {
                "title": f"Report Summary between {date_from} - {date_to}"
            }
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```